# Is $G^{(X, Y)} = (G^X)^Y?$ ($A^B$ just means that $B$ is mapped to $A$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have a set $G=\{banana,potato\}$.To do $G^{(X,Y)}$ ($A^B$ just means that map $(x,y)$ to $G$),I map a Cartesian product $(x,y)$ to every element of $G$,which produce 
$\{((x,y),banana),((x,y),potato)\}$.What if I have $(G^X)^Y$,is it correct if I do $x * y$ first ,then map them to $G$,which produce same element$?$ So is $G^{(X,Y)} = (G^X)^Y?$

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly formatting mathematical functions.

Comment: Can you format this question, so that it is more readable? Also: when you say map $(x,y) \to G$, does this mean mapping $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R} \to G$?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding either what the notation $A^B$ means or what it means to map a codomain to a domain. Nevertheless, it is true that $G^{X\times Y}=(G^X)^Y$, this is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: yeah @AndresMejia... i tried to  format it using mathjack whatever...using  curly braces,but it didnt work...I am not used yet to it

Comment: @SYUU, I see. Well aside from some notation confusion, I think that your statement is correct.

Comment: @Rahul yea i mean B map to A.So to map Y to G^X,just find the (x,y) first,then map the result to G,which will produce same result,and this is called currying?

Comment: To nitpick: these two items are not _equal_ - they have different 'types' and so will technically have different representations - but they are canonically (and naturally, IIRC) _isomorphic_; they can for most practical purposes be thought of as being equal.

Answer (score 1):

$G^{X \times Y}$ and $(G^X)^Y$ are different as sets: the former has all functions that map pairs of points (the first from $X$, the second from $Y$) to points of $G$. The second is the set of all functions that map points from $Y$ to functions (in $G^X)$, and those image functions map points of $X$ to $G$. So the types are different: one is a function of pairs to $G$, the other of single points to functions (that map to $G$ again).

Concretely, take $X = \{1,2\}, Y = \{3,4\}, G = \{5,6\}$, then $G^{X \times Y}$ has elements of the form $\{((1,3),5),((1,4),6),((2,3),6),((2,4),5)\}$, which defines a function from $X \times Y$ to $G$. There are 15 more (there are 4 pairs, for each of which we have 2 independent choices of image from $G$) of course.

The set $(G^X)^Y$ has elements of the form $\{(3,\{(1,5),(2,6)\}), (4,\{(1,6),(2,5)\})\}$, where we have a function (set of pairs) that maps points from $Y$ to a function (another set of pairs!) from $X$ to $G$. Note that there are also 16 of these elements (there are $4 = 2^2$ functions from $X$ to $G$, and we pick one of them for each of the 2 elements of $Y$, so $4 \times 4 = 16$ such functions exist.

I claim that these sets are however naturally bijectively mapped to each other. For each function $f \in G^{X \times Y}$ define a function $F(f) \in (G^X)^Y$ as follows $((F(f))(y))(x) = f(x,y)$. Read this carefully: $F(f)$ is a function from $Y$ to $G^X$ so we must define what its value on $y \in Y$ is: some function from $X$ to $G$, that we again have to define (and here we use the $x$ and $y$ to form a pair and we use the original $f$).

The two example sets from each are in fact each other's image under this map, if you look carefully (and if I made no mistake). One can check that this indeed defines a map (and the inverse map should be a nice exercise to write out).

As an aside (and as mentioned in the comments), this idea of considering maps from pairs as maps of maps, is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in logic/computer science.

So in short, they're not the same, but they are "naturally" isomorphic in a way.